# Question regarding proof that $V = \{ f : \Bbb N \to \Bbb N \mid f(n)\text{ is a prime for all }n \in N\}$ is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm studying for an exam for tomorrow and one of the old exams has this problem:

Given the set $V  = \{  f : \Bbb N \to \Bbb N \mid f(n)\text{ is a prime for all }n \in N \}$

Prove that this set is uncountable. The given proof is as follows:

Assume $V$ is countable. Then $V$ consists of elements $f_0, f_1, \ldots, f_n, \ldots$

Define $g: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ as follows:

$  g(n)=\begin{cases}
    3, & \text{if } f_n(n) \neq 3.\\
    5, & \text{else}.
  \end{cases}
$

Now applies that:

- $g(n) \in \{3,5\}$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$, such that $g \in V$ (because both 3 and 5 are primes)
- Due to its construction $g$ can not be in the list of elements $f_0, f_1, \ldots, f_n, \ldots$ of $V$.

Due to this contradiction we must assume that $V$ is uncountable.

---

My problem is that I do not understand why $g$ can not appear in the list of elements.

Answer (score 7):

Note that $g(n)\neq f_n(n)$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$. Therefore, $g\neq f_n$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: And just like that it all makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another answer, using diagonalization implicitly rather than explicitly. The set of primes is countably infinite, so in one to one correspondence with $\mathbb{N}$. So the set of functions you're counting is essentially the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself, which is known to be uncountable.

Indeed, as @DavidC.Ullrich comments, the argument works if the range is just a two element set. Then you are counting the number of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ - there are uncountably many.

Comment: In fact you only need that there exists more than one prime for that argument...